# Using summary statistics from a paper when the original data are not available

Tags: modeling, missing-data, meta-analysis

There are papers where the authors analyzed data that I would really like to obtain and combine with other data sets in a new analysis. However, because of the age of the papers all I have available to me are summary statistics of the data reported in the papers, e.g., the coefficients from a linear regression. Is there a way to properly use these summary statistics in lieu of the original data in the new analysis?

Comment: It depends on the new analysis.  Perhaps you could edit your post to say something about that?

Comment: I am struggling to describe in a concise way what I want to do with the data. Perhaps the thing that would be most useful at this point would be to know if what I am asking for has a name. In other words, if I went to search for an answer, what would I ask for?

Comment: [tag:meta-analysis] might be what you're thinking of.

Comment: Depending on the information available, you may start from the distribution of these summary statistics and run a statistical analysis based on this distribution.

Comment: Your description would apply to almost any meta-analysis using summary statistics so it is not clear what you are asking.